# When I do not use from a condition I can get the data from php, But when I use from a condition, I Can not get data from php

Tags: java, php, android

My `php` code is correct. But I have a strange problem when I use a condition in my code. My `php` code sends the "A" string from server to android. In the following code when I do not use a condition in my code in the `GetText()` method, I can get the `A` string and display it in the `TextView` well. But when I use a condition as follows, I can not get and display the A string in the `TextView` . Please help me. I do not know that where is this problem.

```
Pass = pass.getText().toString();

// Create data variable for sent values to server

String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

String text = "";
BufferedReader reader = null;

// Send data
try{
   // Defined URL  where to send data
   URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/reg.php");

   // Send POST data request
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
   wr.write(data);
   wr.flush();

   // Get the server response

   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;

   // Read Server Response
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
       // Append server response in string
       sb.append(line);
    }

    text = sb.toString();
} catch(Exception ex){

} finally{
    try{
        reader.close();
    } catch(Exception ex){}
}

// Show response on activity
String A = "A";

if(text.equals(A)){
    content.setText(text); //it can not display the text in the TextView
}
```

}

Comment: Have you try to debug your code? Add a `System.out.println("TEST VARIABLE OUTPUT VALUE: " + test);` after the code: `String A = "A";` Run your app and look on console to see what it is comming. This errors is normally caused by slightly differences on the string like `'A' != 'a'` or `'A'!='A '` note the space;

Comment: Since you `readline` from a stream, you most probably should have a `\n` appended to your string. Hence, `equals` evaluates to `false`.